# A relation between gradient, Hessian, and Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to clarify the relation between gradient, Hessian, and Jacobian. Could you check if my below understanding is fine? Thank you so much!

---

Let $X := \mathbb R^d$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be its canonical inner product. Let $X^*$ be the dual space of $X$, $\mathcal L_{\text{sym}}^2(X, \mathbb R)$ the space of all symmetric bilinear maps from $X \times X$ to $\mathbb R$, and $\mathcal L(X)$ the space of all linear maps from $X$ to $X$. Let $f:X \to \mathbb R$ be twice differentiable at $a \in X$.

1. We have $\partial f (a) \in X^*$. By Riesz representation theorem, there is a unique element in $X$ denoted by $\nabla f (a)$ such that
   $$
   \langle \nabla f (a), x \rangle = \partial f (a) [x] \quad \forall x \in X.
   $$
   Here we use the square bracket $[x]$ to denote the argument of $\partial f (a)$. Then $\nabla f (a)$ is called the **gradient** of $f$ at $a$. We have
   $$
   \nabla f(a)=\left[\begin{array}{c}
   \partial_1 f(a)\\
   \vdots \\
   \partial_d f(a)
   \end{array}\right],
   $$
   where $\partial_k f(a)$ is the partial derivative of $f$ at $a$ w.r.t. the $k$-th coordinate. We also have $\partial_k f(a) = \partial f (a)[e_k]$ where $(e_k)_{k=1}^d$ is the standard basis of $X$.
2. We have $\partial^2 f (a) \in \mathcal L_{\text{sym}}^2(X, \mathbb R)$. Then there is a unique self-adjoint $T \in \mathcal L(X)$ such that
   $$
   \partial^2 f (a)[x, y] = \langle Tx, y \rangle \quad \forall x, y\in X.
   $$
   The operator $T$ can be represented uniquely (in the standard basis) as a square symmetric matrix $H_f (a)$, which is called the **Hessian** of $f$ at $a$. We have
   $$
   H_f (a) :=
   \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   \partial^2_1 f(a)  & \partial_1 \partial_2 f(a) & \cdots & \partial_1 \partial_d f(a) \\
   \partial_2 \partial_1 f(a) & \partial_2^2 f(a) & \cdots & \partial_2 \partial_d f(a) \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   \partial_d \partial_1 f(a) & \partial_d \partial_2 f(a) & \cdots & \partial^2_d f(a)
   \end{array}\right].
   $$
3. It follows from $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$ that $\nabla f:X \to X$ is differentiable at $a$. Let $J_{\nabla f} (a)$ be the **Jacobian** of $\nabla f$ at $a$. So $J_{\nabla f} (a)$ is the unique square $d \times d$ matrix represented $\partial (\nabla f) (a) \in \mathcal L(X)$ (in the standard basis). We have
   $$
   J_{\nabla f} (a) =
   \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
   \partial_1 (\partial_1 f)(a)  & \partial_2 (\partial_1 f)(a) & \cdots & \partial_d (\partial_1 f)(a) \\
   \partial_1 (\partial_2 f)(a) & \partial_2(\partial_2 f)(a) & \cdots & \partial_d (\partial_2 f)(a) \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   \partial_1 (\partial_d f)(a) & \partial_2 (\partial_d f)(a) & \cdots & \partial_d( \partial_d f)(a)
   \end{array}\right].
   $$
   It follows that $J_{\nabla f} (a) = (H_f (a))^\top$ and thus $J_{\nabla f} (a)  = H_f (a)$.